# Android spinner crashing when clicked on

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I have a `spinner` on my page, which is populated using an `arrayAdapter`. When i launch my app everything is ok, but the moment i click on the `spinner`, the app crashes and `logcat` gives me no reference to a line in my code. Here is the area of the code referring to the spinner:

```
profiles = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    SetSql getprofiles = new SetSql(this);
    getprofiles.open();
    spinnerArray = getprofiles.getProfiles();
    if(spinnerArray[0]==null){
        spinnerArray = new String[1];
        spinnerArray[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
    }
    getprofiles.close();

    ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
    array.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    profiles.setAdapter(array);

    //I am using the post method to make sure that this spinner wont run when the activity is started
    profiles.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            profiles.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> ListView, View arg1,
                        int pos, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if(!profiles.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().equals("No Profiles, Please Create One")){
                            String selected = profiles.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, DPAActivity.class);
                            intent.putExtra("username", selected);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        }

    });
```

More logcat:

```
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:376)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:332)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:328)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1409)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1216)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1127)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at com.android.internal.widget.WeightedLinearLayout.onMeasure(WeightedLinearLayout.java:60)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-07 16:25:45.740: E/AndroidRuntime(6929):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**My getProfiles Code**

```
    public void createProfile(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_USER, name);
        ourDatabase.insert(TABLE_USERS, null, cv);
    }

    public String[] getProfiles() throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_USER};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_USERS, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID);
        String[] result = new String[100];

        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER);
        int count = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){ 
            result[count] = c.getString(iName);
            count++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is returning a string array.

Comment: Checked, please look at my new comment on it.

Comment: ckeck new update and please research as this is very basic and if it solved your problem accept it as answer.

Comment: @Siddhesh checked and updated, didn't solve my problem. New Logcat above.

Comment: check sample in answer.

Comment: your code works perfectly on my side. even your `onItemSelectedListener` i dont know why you are using this.profile and even i don't what your `sqler.getProfile()` returns and also don't know where have you written this code. so if possible paste whole class or debug you code http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqHYbm9e05A

Comment: @Siddhesh I have added my `getProfiles()` function, and updated the code i tried to use. So far, the app is launching and working when I have no db entries. But when there is something, it shows on the spinner and when i click the spinner (NOT spinner item) the app crashes.

Comment: try new edit and check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 if(arrayspinner[0]==null){
        arrayspinner = new String[1];
        arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";
    }
```

change your code and try

EDIT:

instead of `Array` try using `ArrayList`

```
List<String> arrayList=Arrays.asList(your string array);
```

or else try to initialize your array by getting the size of your response.

EDIT 2:

```
List<String> a= Arrays.asList(new String[]{});
        if(a.size()==0){
            a=new ArrayList<String>();
        a.add("xxx");
        a.add("bbbb");
        }
        final Spinner s=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, a);
        array.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        s.setAdapter(array);
        s.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

tried a sample same as your code and it works.

EDIT 3:

```
public String[] getProfiles() throws SQLException{
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_USER};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_USERS, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_ROWID);
        String[] result;
        if(c != null && c.getCount()!=0){
        result = new String[c.getCount()];

        int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USER);
        int count = 0;
        for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){ 
            result[count] = c.getString(iName);
            count++;
        }
        }else{
        result = new String[]{"No Profiles, Please Create One"};
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Actually, this worked perfectly until i had more than one item in the list. When that happend, it crashed again :/

Comment: Well, i have never used before an ArrayList so i don't know how to implement it, and trying to initialize my array to a fixed size didn't really work. I did it this way: `arrayspinner = new String[sqler.getProfiles().length]` Since getProfiles() gives back an array i tried to init one with the same length but this didn't help at all.

Comment: Thanks, this is great, just one more problem. When i use this i get an error when trying to check if something was entered into the ArrayList like this: `if(arrayspinner[0]==null)..` and when trying to enter data in manually like this `arrayspinner[0] = "No Profiles, Please Create One";`. How can i fix this?

Comment: This update didn't solve the problem as well. My Logcat is updated above.

Comment: I did it in the same way as you did, but now i get an error even worse - the app just crashes. My code is updating now - check it in a sec.

Comment: `SetSql sqler = new SetSql(UserActivity.this);
  sqler.open();
  List<String> arrayspinner = Arrays.asList(sqler.getProfiles());
  sqler.close();
  if(arrayspinner.size()==0){
   arrayspinner = new ArrayList<String>();
   arrayspinner.add("No Profiles, Please Create One");
  }
  
  ArrayAdapter<String> array = new ArrayAdapter<String>(UserActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, arrayspinner);
  array.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
  profiles.setAdapter(array);` This works when the app launches, but not when the spinner is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Change  if condition inside  `onItemSelected`  as :

```
if(profiles.getItemAtPosition(pos).
                       toString().equals("No Profiles, Please Create One")){
   // your code here....
 }
```

because currently  you are using  `ListView.getItemAtPosition` for getting selected item from Spinner

Comment: This didn't change anything, But i don't think it should matter. The app is not crashing when i am selecting an item, it is crashing when i click the spinner to see the popup with the items in it. Any suggestions?